# Write pandas dataframe into AWS athena database

Tags: python, database, pandas, amazon-athena

I have run a query using pyathena, and have created a pandas dataframe. Is there a way to write the pandas dataframe to AWS athena database directly?
Like data.to_sql for MYSQL database.

Sharing a example of dataframe code below for reference  need to write into AWS athena database:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'name':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],'score':[11,22,33,44,55,66]})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storage for AWS Athena is `S3`. And it reads data from S3 files only. It **was not** possible earlier to write the data directly to `Athena` database like any other database.

`It was missing support support` for `insert into ...`.

As `workaround`, users could have done following steps to make it work.

```
1. You need to write the pandas output to a file, 
2. Save the file to S3 location, from where the AWS Athena is reading.
```

I hope it gives you some pointers.

**Update on 05/01/2020.**

On Sep 19, 2019, `AWS` has announced support for insert to `Athena`, has made one of statement in above answer `incorrect`, though above solution that I have provide will still work, but with `AWS` announcement has added another possible solution going forward.

As `AWS Documentation` suggests, this feature will allow you send `insert` statements and `Athena` will write data back to new file in `source table S3 location`. So essentially, `AWS` has resolved your headache of writing data to back `S3` files.

Just a note, `Athena` will write inserted data into separate files.
Here goes the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/insert-into.html).

Comment: Figured it out, thank u. Accepting your answer too.

Comment: Starting September 2019 AWS Athena supports `insert into` statements. Insert into might be a better approach because you might have less problems with formats and conversions

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/09/amazon-athena-adds-support-inserting-data-into-table-results-of-select-query/

Answer (score 7):

Another modern (as for February 2020) way to achieve this goal is to use [aws-data-wrangler](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/005%20-%20Glue%20Catalog.html#Writing-DataFrames-to-Data-Lake-(S3-+-Parquet-+-Glue-Catalog)) library. It's authomating many routine (and sometimes annoying) tasks in data processing.

Combining the case from the question the code would look like below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import awswrangler as wr

data=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5,6],'name':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],'score':[11,22,33,44,55,66]})

# Typical Pandas, Numpy or Pyarrow transformation HERE!

wr.pandas.to_parquet(  # Storing the data and metadata to Data Lake
    dataframe=data,
    database="database",
    path="s3://your-s3-bucket/path/to/new/table",
    partition_cols=["name"],
)
```

This is amazingly helpful, because [aws-data-wrangler](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/005%20-%20Glue%20Catalog.html#Writing-DataFrames-to-Data-Lake-(S3-+-Parquet-+-Glue-Catalog)) knows to parse table name from the path (but you can provide table name in the parameter) and define proper types in Glue catalog according to the dataframe.

It also helpful for querying the data with Athena directly to pandas dataframe:

```py
df = wr.pandas.read_table(database="dataase", table="table")
```

All the process will be fast and convenient.

Comment: AWS-data-wrangler has updated how to save to parquets in S3. You can check out the updated documentation here: https://readthedocs.org/projects/aws-data-wrangler/downloads/pdf/latest/

Answer (score 4):

The top answer at the time of writing uses an older version of the API, which no longer works.

[The documentation](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) now outlines this round trip.

```py
import awswrangler as wr
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"id": [1, 2], "value": ["foo", "boo"]})

# Storing data on Data Lake
wr.s3.to_parquet(
    df=df,
    path="s3://bucket/dataset/",
    dataset=True,
    database="my_db",
    table="my_table"
)

# Retrieving the data directly from Amazon S3
df = wr.s3.read_parquet("s3://bucket/dataset/", dataset=True)

# Retrieving the data from Amazon Athena
df = wr.athena.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM my_table", database="my_db")
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use:

```
pandas_df.to_parquet(file, engine="pyarrow)
```

To save it first to a temporal file in parquet format. For this you need to install pyarrow dependency. Once this file is saved locally, you can push it to S3 using the aws sdk for python.

A new table in Athena can now be created by executig the following queries:

```
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'your_new_table'
        (col1 type1, col2 type2)
    PARTITIONED BY (col_partitions_if_neccesary)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe'
    LOCATION 's3 location of your parquet file'
    tblproperties ("parquet.compression"="snappy");
```

Another option is to use pyathena for that. Taking the example from their official documentation:

```
import pandas as pd
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn_str = "awsathena+rest://:@athena.{region_name}.amazonaws.com:443/"\
           "{schema_name}?s3_staging_dir={s3_staging_dir}&s3_dir={s3_dir}&compression=snappy"

engine = create_engine(conn_str.format(
    region_name="us-west-2",
    schema_name="YOUR_SCHEMA",
    s3_staging_dir=quote_plus("s3://YOUR_S3_BUCKET/path/to/"),
    s3_dir=quote_plus("s3://YOUR_S3_BUCKET/path/to/")))

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})
df.to_sql("YOUR_TABLE", engine, schema="YOUR_SCHEMA", index=False, if_exists="replace", method="multi")
```

In this case, the dependency sqlalchemy is needed.